# How the LiveData's map transformation does work?

Tags: android, android-livedata

I cannot understand how `LiveData.map` does work. See the code

```kotlin
    private val _numb = MutableLiveData(3)
    val numbPlus = _numb.map { it+1 }

    init {
        val myNumber = numbPlus.value // I expect 4 here but get null

        _numb.value = 6

        val myNumber2 = numbPlus.value // I expect 7 here but get null
```

Why I am not getting the values I expect? And how can I make `numbPlus` to reflect data in `_numb`?

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the source code of LiveData's setValue(T value)

First of all, your `map` must be effective. You also have an effect on `_numb.value = 6`, but you cannot read the value directly from `_numb.value`.
You need to get the latest value from LiveData's Observer.

The latest value will be observed by all LiveData Observers. You can get the latest value in the observer. As for why you get `_numb.value` as null after setting `_numb.value = 6`, It is because the real data exchange will only be reflected in `observers`, `getValue()` will judge the equality of your `value` object with an `Object` object called `NOT_SET` in LiveData, otherwise it will directly return as `null`

```kotlin
public T getValue() {
         Object data = mData;
         if (data != NOT_SET) {
             return (T) data;
         }
         return null;
     }
```

The correct way to use:

```kotlin
    private val _numb = MutableLiveData(3)
    val numbPlus = _numb.map { it + 1 }

    init {
        _numb.value = 6
    }
```

Here are my observers:

```kotlin
        viewModel.numbPlus.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            println("xxxxxxK:${viewModel.numbPlus.value}")
            println("xxxxxx:${it}")
        })
```

final result:

```
2021-05-27 20:02:56.085 13713-13713/com.lonbon.lonbon_app I/System.out: xxxxxxK:7
2021-05-27 20:02:56.085 13713-13713/com.lonbon.lonbon_app I/System.out: xxxxxx:7
```

Comment: Can you include a snippet of the source code that makes `setValue` asynchronous?

Comment: `_numb.value = 6`  It is essentially setValue(), I have already called the setValue() method in the initialization block

Comment: Sorry but that doesn't seem relevant to my question. You inferred in your answer that `setValue` is asynchronous, so I was wondering where you've seen that?

Comment: About my understanding of LiveData's synchronization and asynchrony yesterday was wrong. I am very sorry about this, LiveData is just a convenient container for notifying observers.

Comment: I have changed the statement in my answer, thank you, I sincerely express my gratitude, you really helped me a lot.